# Faster, better, and more efficient type hinting for PHP Storm with service locators

Tags: php, zend-framework2, phpstorm, service-locator

I have been looking for a way to do this for months. I am one of those developers that loves autocompletion. For every Service Locator call in zend framework 2 I type hint with the following:

### Without global hinting file

```
/** @var \Module\Service\SuperService $superService */ 
$superService => $this->getServiceLocator()>get('\Module\Service\SuperService');
$superService->coolFunction();
```

This works, but the code can get messy when you start getting 2-4 Services in a single Controller. I am trying to find a better way to use PHP Storm and type hinting for service locator calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this doesn't help you now, it's useful for you to know that we are close to supporting this out of the box, with a few provisos:

1. The container needs to implement the Container Interop project's `Container\Interop\ContainerInterface` which ZF2's ServiceManager already does.
2. You need to use the `::class` super-global-hyper-magic-contant to name and retrieve your classes. In your case, simply replace the string in your `get` call with `Module\Service\SuperService::class` (available from PHP 5.4 and above).

I'm expecting this functionality to be available in our next release, PhpStorm 2016.2 which is due around the summer.

Gary

Comment: That is wonderful news. My entire company is excited for this.

Comment: If you would like to get this functionality right now, simply add a .phpstorm.meta.php file to your project root with the following contents: https://gist.github.com/GeeH/6609d26f78a352d5f4609b1da3bb73ea

Comment: @GeeH Is there a youtrack issue to follow with regards to this? Also, is there a performance gain to switch to this newer method than phpstorm.meta.php?

Answer (score 4):

About a month ago PHP Storm released a new feature that allows for a static file to be used for type hinting. I personally use this just for the service locator but it can be used for many other things that PHP Storm can't follow because it's not magic.

### With global hinting file

```
$superService = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('\Module\Service\SuperService');
$superService->coolFunction();
```

This does a few things for us as developers:

- Teamwork (others will be able to see all services at once from all
  modules)
- Coding
- Speed
- Code neatness
- Code Standards
- Click to go to the class faster

### What to do

In the **project ROOT** (same place as **composer.json**), there should (create if not) be a file called **.phpstorm.meta.php** This file contains the static hinting and which instance they use.

To add your own, simply toss it inside the existing file

***WARNING*** - If you declare the wrong class, you will end up writing the code wrong, and confused... it has happened to me a bunch

---

I am including my current Config which is personal to my project but gives more of an understanding of what to do.

```
namespace PHPSTORM_META {
    $STATIC_METHOD_TYPES = [
        \Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface::get('') => [

            /**
             * Common services
             */
            'doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default' instanceof \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager,
            'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' instanceof \Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory,

            /** Custom to Project */
            'RiotAdapter' instanceof \GameService\Service\RiotAdapter,
            'SmiteAdapter' instanceof \GameService\Service\SmiteAdapter,
            'GameService' instanceof \GameService\Service\GameService,

        ],
    ];
}
```

If you would like more information on this, you can look @ a confluence post from PHP Storm [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Advanced+Metadata)