# Automatic type-hinting for Zend Studio service locators

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-studio, type-hinting, service-locator

My question is almost identical to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33834046/faster-better-and-more-efficient-type-hinting-for-php-storm-with-service-locat), however it is regarding a different IDE.

When using a service in Zend Framework 2, I use code similar to the following:

```
$myService = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('MyService');
```

However, I have to manually add in type-hinting for the service for autocomplete to work:

```
/** @var \Module\Service\MyService $myService */
```

This is useful as it means you get the information on what parameters to give to functions, for example, without having to open the class and find the function. But when there are many services it starts to get clunky having multiple type-hints, especially for larger projects that have 7 or 8 services being used. Of course, these type-hints must be added to each individual controller and action as well; a time-consuming task.

So, my question - **is there a way in Zend Studio (13.5) to automatically type-hint all services in the project?**

#### Edit

I declare services in the `Module.php` file with code similar to the following:

```
public function getServiceConfig() {
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'MyService' => function ($sm) {
                $dbAdapter = $sm->get('db');
                $sql = new Sql($dbAdapter);
                return new MyService($sql);
            }
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the service by `::class` identifier? Eg. `$this->getServiceLocator()->get(Service\MyService::class)`?

Comment: @gsc I've just tried it now and auto-complete doesn't work, and I then get an exception on the page: `Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for...`. This may be due to how I load my services though (have edited question with details). Don't know if I should be changing something in the `Module.php` file to get the `::class` identifier to work?

Comment: You can (temporarily?) create an alias to your service — put `'aliases' => [MyService::class => 'MyService']` above that `factories` key. I assume you understand basics of namespaces. Then try again with my first comment. In long-term, I’d use `MyService::class` as the only identifier and initialize it in a dedicated factory class, but that’s a different story.

Comment: @gsc that got rid of the exception, however still doesn't give me the autocomplete unfortunately. I'll have to look into using factories at some point - when I started on ZF2, their documentation was appalling so it was a case of getting something to work, and doing it the same way forever more!!